# Load checkpoint and finetuning using tf.estimator.Estimator

Tags: tensorflow

We're trying to translate old training code based into a more tf.estimator.Estimator compliant code. 
In the initial code we fine tune an original model for a target dataset. Only some layers are loaded from the checkpoint before the training takes place using a combination of **variables_to_restore** and **init_fn** with the **MonitoredTrainingSession**.
How can one achieve this kind of weight loading with the tf.estimator.Estimator approach ?

Comment: Did you manage to make this work? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: To anyone stumbling here hoping for a solution, the problem was fixed (with an actual example) here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47867748/3214872

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer learning with tf.estimator.Estimator framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47867748/transfer-learning-with-tf-estimator-estimator-framework)

Answer (score 5):

you have two options, first one is simpler:

1- use `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint` in your `model_fn`

2- `model_fn` returns an `EstimatorSpec`. You can set scaffold via`EstimatorSpec`.

Comment: How do I `init_from_checkpoint` specifying a list of variables to restore from the checkpoint? From what I can see, I can only pass scope names as map keys/values

Answer (score 4):

```
import tensorflow as tf    

def model_fn():
  # your model defintion here
  # ...

# specify your saved checkpoint path
checkpoint_path = "model.ckpt"

ws = tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings(ckpt_to_initialize_from=checkpoint_path)
est = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, warm_start_from=ws)
```