# Transfer learning with tf.estimator.Estimator framework

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to do transfer learning of an Inception-resnet v2 model pretrained on imagenet, using my own dataset and classes.
My original codebase was a modification of a `tf.slim` sample which I can't find anymore and now I'm trying to rewrite the same code using the `tf.estimator.*` framework.

I am running, however, into the problem of loading only *some* of the weights from the pretrained checkpoint, initializing the remaining layers with their default initializers.

Researching the problem, I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10155) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423956/load-checkpoint-and-finetuning-using-tf-estimator-estimator), both mentioning the need to use `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint` in my `model_fn`. I tried, but given the lack of examples in both, I guess I got something wrong.

This is my minimal example:

```
import sys
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import inception_resnet_v2

NUM_CLASSES = 900
IMAGE_SIZE = 299

def input_fn(mode, num_classes, batch_size=1):
  # some code that loads images, reshapes them to 299x299x3 and batches them
  return tf.constant(np.zeros([batch_size, 299, 299, 3], np.float32)), tf.one_hot(tf.constant(np.zeros([batch_size], np.int32)), NUM_CLASSES)


def model_fn(images, labels, num_classes, mode):
  with tf.contrib.slim.arg_scope(inception_resnet_v2.inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()):
    logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2.inception_resnet_v2(images,
                                             num_classes, 
                                             is_training=(mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN))
  predictions = {
      'classes': tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
      'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='softmax_tensor')
  }

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

  exclude = ['InceptionResnetV2/Logits', 'InceptionResnetV2/AuxLogits']
  variables_to_restore = tf.contrib.slim.get_variables_to_restore(exclude=exclude)
  scopes = { os.path.dirname(v.name) for v in variables_to_restore }
  tf.train.init_from_checkpoint('inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt',
                                {s+'/':s+'/' for s in scopes})
  
  tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=labels, logits=logits)
  total_loss = tf.losses.get_total_loss()    #obtain the regularization losses as well
  
  # Configure the training op
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.00002)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(total_loss, global_step)
  else:
    train_op = None
  
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    mode=mode,
    predictions=predictions,
    loss=total_loss,
    train_op=train_op)

def main(unused_argv):
  # Create the Estimator
  classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=lambda features, labels, mode: model_fn(features, labels, NUM_CLASSES, mode),
      model_dir='model/MCVE')

  # Train the model  
  classifier.train(
      input_fn=lambda: input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, NUM_CLASSES, batch_size=1),
      steps=1000)
    
  # Evaluate the model and print results
  eval_results = classifier.evaluate(
      input_fn=lambda: input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL, NUM_CLASSES, batch_size=1))
  print()
  print('Evaluation results:\n    %s' % eval_results)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]])
```

where `inception_resnet_v2` is [the model implementation in Tensorflow's models repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py).

If I run this script, I get a bunch of info log from `init_from_checkpoint`, but then, at session creation time, it seems it attempts to load the `Logits` weights from the checkpoint and fails because of incompatible shapes. This is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-06fadd69ae8f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/1/Desktop/transfer_learning_tutorial-master/MCVE.py', wdir='C:/Users/1/Desktop/transfer_learning_tutorial-master')

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/1/Desktop/transfer_learning_tutorial-master/MCVE.py", line 77, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]])

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))

  File "C:/Users/1/Desktop/transfer_learning_tutorial-master/MCVE.py", line 68, in main
    steps=1000)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 302, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 780, in _train_model
    log_step_count_steps=self._config.log_step_count_steps) as mon_sess:

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 368, in MonitoredTrainingSession
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 673, in __init__
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 493, in __init__
    self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 851, in __init__
    _WrappedSession.__init__(self, self._create_session())

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 856, in _create_session
    return self._sess_creator.create_session()

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 554, in create_session
    self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 428, in create_session
    init_fn=self._scaffold.init_fn)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\session_manager.py", line 279, in prepare_session
    sess.run(init_op, feed_dict=init_feed_dict)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)

  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)

InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [900] rhs shape= [1001]    [[Node: Assign_1145 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT,
_class=["loc:@InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Logits/biases"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Logits/biases, checkpoint_initializer_1145)]]
```

What am I doing wrong when using `init_from_checkpoint`? How exactly are we supposed to "use" it in our `model_fn`? And why is the estimator trying to load the `Logits`' weights from the checkpoint when I'm explicitly telling it not to?

### Update:

After the suggestion in the comments, I tried alternative ways to call `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint`.

#### Using `{v.name: v.name}`

If, as suggested in the comment, I replace the call with `{v.name:v.name for v in variables_to_restore}`, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Assignment map with scope only name InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_2a_3x3 should map
to scope only InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_2a_3x3/weights:0. Should be 'scope/': 'other_scope/'.
```

#### Using `{v.name: v}`

If, instead, I try using the `name:variable` mapping, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Tensor InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_2a_3x3/weights:0 is not found in
inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt checkpoint
{'InceptionResnetV2/Repeat_2/block8_4/Branch_1/Conv2d_0c_3x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean': [256], 
'InceptionResnetV2/Repeat/block35_9/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/BatchNorm/beta': [32], ...
```

The error continues listing what I think are all the variable names in the checkpoint (or could it be the scopes instead?).

### Update (2)

After inspecting the latest error here above, I see that `InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_2a_3x3/weights` **is** in the list of the checkpointed variables. **The problem is that `:0` at the end!**
I'll now verify if this does indeed solve the problem and post an answer if that's the case.

Comment: Are there any checkpoints in the estimator directory `model/MCVE`?

Comment: No, the directory is empty

Comment: Perhaps the line `scopes = { os.path.dirname(v.name) for v in variables_to_restore }` is adding `InceptionResnetV2` to the list of scopes, so all variables under `InceptionResnetV2/` will be loaded. Instead of building a list of scopes, you could try listing the variables directly: `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint('inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt',
                                {v.name:v.name for v in variables})`

Comment: That is possible, yes. However, if I try to use your suggested code, I get this error: `ValueError: Assignment map with scope only name InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_2a_3x3 should map to scope only InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_2a_3x3/weights:0. Should be 'scope/': 'other_scope/'.`. It seems variable names have to be used in a different way

Comment: If you're making the complete switch from `slim`, consider using `tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_to_restore`. It's similar, but just a matter of bookkeeping (annoying one).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @KathyWu's comment, I got on the right track and found the problem.

Indeed, the way I was computing the `scopes` would include the `InceptionResnetV2/` scope, that would trigger the load of **all** variables "under" the scope (i.e., all variables in the network). Replacing this with the correct dictionary, however, was not trivial.

Of the possible scope modes [`init_from_checkpoint` accepts](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/init_from_checkpoint), the one I had to use was the `'scope_variable_name': variable` one, **but without using the actual `variable.name` attribute**.

The `variable.name` looks like: `'some_scope/variable_name:0'`. **That `:0` is not in the checkpointed variable's name** and so using `scopes = {v.name:v.name for v in variables_to_restore}` will raise a "Variable not found" error.

The trick to make it work was **stripping the tensor index from the name**:

```
tf.train.init_from_checkpoint('inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt', 
                              {v.name.split(':')[0]: v for v in variables_to_restore})
```

Answer (score 1):

I find out `{s+'/':s+'/' for s in scopes}` didn't work, just because the `variables_to_restore` include something like `"global_step"`, so scopes include the global scopes which could include everything. You need to print `variables_to_restore`, find `"global_step"` thing, and put it in `"exclude"`.